# Keep value in form after submitting PHP

Tags: php, forms

I'm calling these functions from a controller to get the form and the values from the form. My question is, how can I keep the values in the form after a submit fails? I've tried something like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="myField1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myField1']) ? $_POST['myField1'] : '' ?>" />
```

but can't get it to work.

```
private $m_username = 'username';
private $m_password = 'password';
private $m_registerButton = 'registerButton';

public function RegisterUserBox(){
    return
    '<form method="post">
            <fieldset>
                Username: <input type="text" name="'.$this->m_username.'" />
                Password: <input type="password" name="'.$this->m_password.'" />
                <input type="submit" value="Register" name="'.$this->m_registerButton.'"/>
            </fieldset>
     </form>';

}

public function GetUsername(){
    if(isset($_POST[$this->m_username])){
        return $_POST[$this->m_username];
    }
}

public function GetPassword(){
    if (isset($_POST[$this->m_password])){
        return $_POST[$this->m_password];
    }
}

public function TriedToRegister(){
    if (isset($_POST[$this->m_registerButton])){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That looks fine to me, the top bit of code. It just never fills in?

Comment: Best answers to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514897/keep-form-values-after-submit-php

Comment: Just keep getting syntax error when I use the top bit of code, and can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: what is the text of the syntax error?

Comment: I upvoted your answer because this is an important concept

Answer (score 1):

`[edit: run this on localhost]`

`autocomplete` does not work on all browsers; moreover, it is only a hint, so cookies are the only option left. The solution below works fine, however **it will be great if other users contribute alternate ways for this popular request :** `Keep value in form after submitting`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }

        function store() {
            var inputs, index;

            inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (index = 0; index < inputs.length - 1; ++index) {
                setCookie(inputs[index].name,inputs[index].value,1);
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="post" action="back.php" onsubmit="store()" >
      firstname<input type="text" name="firstname">
      lastname<input type="text" name="lastname">
      emailid<input type="text" name="emailid">
      <input type="submit" >
    </form>
    <script>
        (function load(){
            var inputs, index;

            inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (index = 0; index < inputs.length - 1; ++index) {
                inputs[index].value = getCookie(inputs[index].name);
            }
            return false;
        })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: image-1]
[image: image-2]
[image: image-3]
[image: image-4]

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>

    <form method="post" action="back.php" autocomplete="on" >
      <input type="text" autocomplete="on" >
      <input type="submit" >
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use that method :D no extra charges, simple plain html :D

Comment: But this don't keep the values in the fields, just predicts the value, right?

Comment: it can keep, but i am checking it on all browsers, and also working on javascript way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Before your form, instantiate the object which will receive the `$_POST` data

```
$userbox = new Userbox;
```

Then process `$_POST` data, if there is any:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] === 'userboxsubmit'){
  $userbox->process_post(); 
}
```

Then output the form:

```
<input type="text" name="myField1" value="<?php echo $userbox->myField1; ?>" />
```