# Preserving a select option after PHP submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a html select box with a list of countries. When I select one, it posts to the PHP method with no problem, but the select box resets to the top. How can I preserve the value that the user selected here? My code is here (for brevity's sake, I've taken out most of the other countries)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <select name="countryCd"  onChange="submit();return false;">
                <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="ALA">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="ALB">Albania</option>
            </select>
        </form>

    <?php echo $_POST["countryCd"]; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may find this question useful:

[Keep form values after submit PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514897/keep-form-values-after-submit-php)

Essentially you can use something like:

```
<select name="countryCD">
      <option value="AFG" 
         <?php if(isset($_POST['countryCD']) && $_POST['countryCD'] == 'AFG') 
         echo 'selected= "selected"';
          ?>
      >Afghanistan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<select name="countryCd"  onChange="submit();return false;">
    <option value="AFG" <?= $_POST['countyCd'] == AFG ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="ALA" <?= $_POST['countyCd'] == ALA ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="ALB" <?= $_POST['countyCd'] == ALB ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Albania</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to each OPTION.  You will need to change *this value* for each.

```
<?php if($_POST['countryCd'] == '*this value*'){ php?>selected<?php } php?>
```