# trying to make php select drop down retain its values on submit

Tags: php

Am a php novice and in need of some help. Basically I have a script that populates a drop down select bar using php. I want to retain the value the user selects in this drop down after submission, so the user does not have to select it again, here is the snippet of the script that I am trying to work with.

```
   <?php
// Start the session
session_start();

$_SESSION["dir"] = $_POST['hiddenVal'];
//echo "hi at last" .$_SESSION["dir"];
?>

<script>
function loadValues()
{
var $x=obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value = $x;
//alert(document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value);
}
</script>

<script>

  function country(obj){
  //alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value); //if you want to show in alart
  //or put in a variable 
  var $x=obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value = $x;
  alert($x);

  }

 </script>

 <body onload="loadValues();">

 <form action="dir20.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden"  id="hiddenVal" name = "hiddenVal"/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
 </body>













<?php
$path = '/docdownloads';
//echo  'php_'.$abc;

$dirs = array();

// directory handle
$dir = dir($path);

while (false !== ($entry = $dir->read())) {
    if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
       if (is_dir($path . '/' .$entry)) {
            $dirs[] = $entry; 
            //echo "$entry</br>";

       }
    }
}










?>

<select name="country" id="country"  onChange="country(this)" required>
<!--<option value="">-----------------</option>-->
<?php
    asort($dirs);
    reset($dirs); 
    foreach($dirs as $p => $w):
        echo '<option value="'.$w.'">'.$w.'</option>'; //close your tags!!
    endforeach;
?>
</select>







<?php
$tex = $_SESSION["dir"];

//$def = "docdownloads";

//$dir = "c:/".$tex;
$dir = "c:/docdownloads/".$tex;
//echo "tex is". "$dir";
echo "</br>";
//if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            echo "$entry</br>";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Tip: Use meaningful variable names.  These are very abstract, and don't convey any meaning to the programmer, making the code a bit of a "puzzle" for someone who might try and debug / maintain it in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving a select option after PHP submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503607/preserving-a-select-option-after-php-submit)

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to check the $_GET var against the selected option. If the current option exists and it has been selected, then give the option the selected attribute.

-----------------

```
<?php
    asort($dirs);
    reset($dirs); 
    foreach($dirs as $p => $w):

        $selected = isset($_GET['country']) && $_GET['country'] === $w ? "selected" : "";
        echo '<option value="'.$w.'"'.$selected.'>'.$w.'</option>';
    endforeach;
?>
</select>
```

Comment: As a member of SO who is now building some reputation, may I encourage you that your first job is to be a _steward_ of SO, not to necessarily answer questions.  This question is so fundamental, one should do some searching and you would discover it is _duplicate_, which means you should [vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) the question rather than answering it.  I recognize you don't have that reputation yet, but you _do_ have the reputation to leave a comment that identifies the duplicate.

Comment: Hi Juakali92, have tried your solution but its still the same, the values from the select are not being retained.

Comment: is your form method set to post?

Comment: yes, form method is set to post, changed your solution to post too, still not working

Comment: you should probably post more of your code then if that's the case to understand a little more whats going on. View the page source to see if your option values are being set. Var dump $_POST to see what's being returned. Then you can check the difference.

Comment: Hi Jukali, here is the rest of the code, hope it helps

Comment: Hi Juakali92, my apologies, have added the rest of the code in my edit

Comment: you're posting the content to another file: dir20.php. So you're sending the data way from the script. Also you seem to be missing your <html> and <head> tags also.

Comment: No, just used dir20.php instead of php_self.

Comment: You need to put your select element inside your form. Otherwise it won't submit

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign a ID for user if you havent already, then save the submitted option in your database with corresponding ID. Then when you load you'r dropdown box insert a IF clause in your script to check if user has already saved a option.

Comment: OP says on submit, not on save, and makes no mention of a database.  Why are you mentioning a DB solution?

Comment: When you use PHP and want a solution like this, it is very easy to make us of a DB. Also, when you store the value in a DB, you can retrieve this value later if you need it

Comment: OP wants to retrieve submitted data. Where is he going to retrieve it from?

Comment: After OP submits the form/select you can store the value and then in further submissions you can retrieve the value. Sure, the first time the user needs to select the value manually.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you should save the value the user chose into session
and always when displaying the form, you should check if the value exists in the session and if it exists - display it as selected option.

Answer (score 0):

get the submitted value of country by `GET` or `POST`(depend on your form `method`) and compare it in `foreach` loop

```
$countryId = isset($_POST['country']) ? $_POST['country'] : ''; //or $_GET['country'];
foreach($dirs as $p => $w):
    $selected = $countryId==$w ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option value="'.$w.'" '.$selected.'>'.$w.'</option>';
    endforeach;
```

Assuming your form `action` is on same page, if different, store country value in `session` and retrieve it from `session` in this page

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote You need to put your select element inside your form. Otherwise it won't submit

problem solved, script now works, many thanks!