# avoid reloading page or resetting select dropdowns with php

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP programming and working with backend. I know what I am doing, but having trouble finding a proper solution online which matches my case. 
Basically, I have a form (2 text fields, 3 dropdowns) that filters the data that I am getting from SQL Server (that works). However, when I press the "filter" button and I get the desired results, the page reloads and resets the form. Now I have the filtered records but I don't know what filters I used to get that.
 I could insert a `<?php ... ?>` if else, but the thing is I already am using php to get the dropdown values. Don't think I can put php inside php.
By including if-else I mean this:
`echo '<option value="' . $row['status'] . '"' . if($prod_status == $row['status']): echo ' selected="selected"' . '>' . $row['status'] . '</option>';`

 Here's the code:

```php
<label for="prod_status_filter">Prod Status</label>
<select class="form-control" id="prod_status_filter" name="prod_status_filter">
<?php
    $query_status = 'select DISTINCT status FROM analytics.laborrecords ORDER BY status ASC';
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_status);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['status'] . '">' . $row['status'] . '</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

This is one of the dropdowns.

I want:
1. Either stop the page from reloading so the filter dropdowns remain the same. (AJAX won't work, I have 3 dropdowns with a lot of options and it's doesn't seem like a good practice to make so many getElementById lines)
2. Let the page reload but keep the values as I set until I want to reset them, with a "reset" button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503607/preserving-a-select-option-after-php-submit

Comment: … or of lots of others, https://www.google.com/search?q=php+select+field+preserve+selected+option+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: You could do a prepared statement with the data sent by your form, so the filtering will be done directly in SQL. Or you could manipulate your dropdowns with Javascript when the *Filter* button is clicked. There are many solutions for your issue.

Comment: @04Fs, I always extensive research on Google and this website before asking a question, and as I said everything I found was not exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Well then explain _how exactly_ it wasn’t what you were looking for. Just stating that makes very little sense, we can not look inside your head and magically know what you want instead.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not stating my question as you want, but I think I clarified that I cannot put if-else statements in the option values. I also put 2 points at the end of what I want and what I have tried.

Comment: _“Don't think I can put php inside php”_ - no, you can’t. But you don’t have to output every static part of HTML using echo to begin with - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15503886/10955263 in the linked duplicate for an example. Using the ternary operator would be another option, you can do that “inside” of an echo.

Comment: @04FS I would not be able to use the while statement to get all options if I do that. Can I split the while statement in 2 php tags?

Comment: @04FS I found the solution by using ternary operator, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: _“Can I split the while statement in 2 php tags?”_ - you can “break out of” a PHP block pretty much anywhere. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to populate the form using the submitted form data. It should be either in `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Check if the value of `$_POST['prod_status_filter']` matches the value in `$row['status']` and if it does, echo selected.

Be sure to sanitize the form data. **Never trust user input.**

Comment: This is what I meant by doing the if-else thing, but the page does not load if I enter that snippet. Here's what I tried and page didn't load: `echo '<option value="' . $row['status'] . '"' . if($prod_status == $row['status']): echo ' selected="selected"' . '>' . $row['status'] . '</option>';` I'll include this snippet in the question too.

Comment: You can't put an echo inside an echo. Pretty sure you can't put an if in there either. Try a ternary operator instead of an if: `($prod_status == $row['status'] ? ' selected="selected"' : "")`

Comment: Tried that, the page load. The dropdown has the number of values I want but they're blank. I tried filtering and it works but I cannot see the text anymore. Maybe it's because we're adding the if-else at the same time we're creating the option itself?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to close the option with '>'. The ternary operator was the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HarshdipSinghDeogan This is pretty much chapter 1 PHP basics. It won't hurt to just buy a good PHP book and work it through to get your head around some coding basics.

Comment: I just didn't know that I cannot use if-else in PHP echo tags and I've never had to use ternary operators so I didn't think of it.