# Saving form values dependant upon onclick/onchange functions

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form that saves user entered values on submit with php.
Some of the fields are in div's that are display:hidden until an onclick or onchange function changes that div to show.

How can I show only the divs containing fields with saved values after the form has been submitted? I have saved the values in the always visible fields but cannot trigger their functions.

I am using very little jquery because I am new to the syntax and would prefer to implement solutions I can understand and adapt. Simple jquery is acceptable if it is a better/quicker/easier solution.

Thanks

Code Example:

```
<input type="radio" id="customer" name="jobtype" value="customer" onclick="getJobType()" autofocus>Customer
<input type="radio" id="store" name="jobtype" value="store" onclick="getJobType()">Store
<span id="customerjobs" style="display:none">
    <select id="customer" name="customer" onchange="createJobsList(this.value)">
    *various options*
    </select>

    <span id="jobslist"><br></span>
</span>
```

The first span (id=customerjobs) is initially hidden. Upon selection from the radio's, all but the corresponding span is set to display:none and the selected is set to display:block. On submit, the selected radio is saved, but the onclick isn't called to show the span.

The second span (id=jobslist) content is populated by innerHTML using the results of an ajax call to PHP when a selection is made. On submit, the selected option is saved, but the onchange isn't called to fill the span.

So I need to trigger the onclick of a saved radio value to show my content and trigger the onchange of a saved select to populate additional content.

Note: I used onblur with javascript to set the focus initially so any action would trigger the content but it caused an unnecessary pause in filling the form that I didn't want.

1. Page loads with only a radio selection.
2. User clicks radio button.
3. Onclick function changes style of span id=customerjobs to display:block.
4. The select input inside the span is now visible. The user selects an option.
5. Onchange function makes an ajax call to request information from the server which is placed in span id=jobslist.
6. User submits form to same page.
7. Form saves entered values so they are still selected when page reloads.
8. Onclick and onchange functions are not triggered by PHP saved values so steps 3 and 5 never occur. Page is left with only the radio buttons unless it is clicked again.

Well, I have a jsfiddle to illustrate my problem using default selections because I cannot use PHP to save entered values. 
Imagine the form has just been submitted and the values saved are the checked radio button(customer) and the selection from the drop down(1) which adds the word "customer". 
Ideally, the entire form would still be visible (The selected radio, the selected option and the content added to the last span "customer"). 
Instead, only the selected radio is visible unless it is clicked again to unhide the select drop down. The drop down retains its' value as well, but the content in the last span will only appear onchange.

http://jsfiddle.net/L5H2u/31/

Try it out and advance thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide more info and/or example of your preferred solution and what you get now

Comment: I still don't understand what you need to achieve exactly. Can you please provide steps of what you are doing (numbered or something) so we can try to solve this? :)

Comment: Added a step by step of the way the page is operating initially and on submit.

Comment: [Try this answer!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514897/keep-form-values-after-submit-php)

Comment: I actually have not implemented the saved radio value, so I forgot that isn't in my code example. Instead, I was using the first radio checked by default, that was my discovery of the onclick/onchange problem. Thanks for the link as reference, amarnath.
Step 8 is the problem I am having though, not saved values.

Comment: ahh - i would really like to see your problem in action. Do you have a link maybe?

Comment: I am new to this, if I go to jsfiddle, I can build an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you hook a function to onload that checks the radio buttons and simulates the click by calling getJobtype()?  That will get the initial case where the radio button is already the way the user wants it.  Further clicks will work as you planned.

*Edited to add:* If I understand you right, all is well the first time the page is loaded because the user has to click something and that runs your getJobType() function.  However, when the page is reloaded, the correct radio button is already checked, the user doesn't change anything, and your function doesn't run.  If that's correct, running getJobType() from onload should fix it.

You may need something like `<input type="hidden" id="firstrun" value="true">` The PHP would set that to `false` on subsequent loads of the page, and the onload function would only make things happen if "firstrun" was false.  Edit: You don't need this because getJobType() has no default action; keep reading.

*Edited still more:*  You have `checked="checked'` on the Customer radio button, so if the user is a customer, even the initial run doesn't reveal the hidden material.

Remove `checked="checked"` when the page is initially loaded so that on the initial presentation, neither button is checked.*  Then add `window.onload=getJobType;` to the end of your JavaScript.

On the initial load, getJobType() will do nothing since it checks both buttons and has no default action.  When a button is clicked, getJobType() will run and act based on the button that was clicked.

When the page is loaded a subsequent time, one of the buttons will be checked and when `onload` runs getJobType() it will perform the corresponding action.

The radio buttons, SELECT values, and any other form elements that are preserved and "reflected" by the server-side PHP will be correct when the form is loaded the second (and subsequent) times.  Where you need an `onload` JavaScript function is when one of those values *also* changes something else, such as making a hidden DIV visible.  If there are functions other than getJobType() that manipulate the DOM, it will likely be cleaner to write an `init` function that sets up the DOM based on the values of the form elements as preserved by the PHP process.

`*` I normally advocate having *some* button checked by default so that the user can always get back to the initial state.  This case seems to be an exception.

Comment: Thanks Bob, the checked="checked" was to simulate a saved value and is normally not there, so this works for getJobType. But for createJobsList and createStoreList, the selected option value is passed to the function. How can I handle this onload?

Comment: In the example, this option value is unused, but in my code, it is used in an ajax call.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all you need is `window.onload=getJobType;` in your JavaScript, after getJobType() is defined.

Comment: The value of the select is saved by PHP also (if...selected="selected"). I need to call its' onchange function onload also to load the rest of the content.

Comment: Stack Overflow appears to frown on extended discussions in comments, so I've edited my post to address your concern.

Comment: Thanks - I used getElementById to pull the saved value of my select element and passed it properly to the ajax function in my onload.