# Keeping PHP form text visible after I hit submit

Tags: php, forms

I'm setting up a form where the user has to enter text into several fields to load into a database, then hit submit.  The form is validated after the user hits submit to make all the necessary data has been entered.  I want to keep the data in the text field visible though after subnit but so far I haven't been able to get that to happen.  I tried using value="" to retain the data, but the code shows up in the text field instead of it being blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang = "en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
    <title>Tech Order Department.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>New Projects</h2>
     <?php
      if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {

        $varProject = $_POST['Project'];
        $varClient = $_POST['Client'];
        $varLastName = $_POST['LastName'];
        $varDateReceived = $_POST['DateReceived'];
    }
    ?>
    <form action="Form.php" method="post" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars    ($_GET['lastname']); ?>" >
        Project:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Project"><br>
        Client:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Client">
        <br>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="LastName">
        <br>
        Date Received:<br>
        <input type="text" name="DateReceived">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>   
    <?php

     if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {
        $errorMessage = "";
        if (empty($_POST['Project'])) {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a project name!</li>";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['Client'])) {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a client name!</li>";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['LastName'])) {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter the tech writer name!    </li>";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['DateReceived'])) {
            $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter the date received!    </li>";
        }
        $varProject = $_POST['Project'];
        $varclient = $_POST['Client'];
        $varLastName = $_POST['LastName'];
        $varDateReceived = $_POST['DateReceived'];
        if (!empty($errorMessage)) {
            echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
            echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For other types of fields that aren't inputs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514897/keep-form-values-after-submit-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use value="" on the text field, not the form.

```
<input value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['Project']) ? $_REQUEST['Project']:''); ?>" name="Project" type="text" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$_POST` be more appropriate in this case?

Comment: @user1122069   I added the code you suggested.  The code no longer shows up in the text field, but the data entered still erases on submit.

Comment: It needed an echo. try again. @allejo

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the submitted value in value attribute of input element.

Your code will be something like below:

```
$varProject = "";
$varClient = "";
$varLastName = "";
$varDateReceived = "";
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {

    $varProject = $_POST['Project'];
    $varClient = $_POST['Client'];
    $varLastName = $_POST['LastName'];
    $varDateReceived = $_POST['DateReceived'];
}
```

In the HTML, it should be:

```
<input type="text" name="Project" value="<?php echo $varProject?>"><br>
```

Comment: the problem is the code shows up in the "value" statement.